# How to convert an int values consisting of various ASCII codes to its corresponding word string?

Tags: python

Say I have a bunch of ASCII codes joined into one int value. For e.g. - My name "Rahul" yields 8297104117108(`x =''.join(str(ord(c))for c in "Rahul"`). How do I convert this integer back to the word that is formed using the ASCII codes?

Comment: Please clarify how "Rahul" yields 8297104117108.

Comment: look at the first character, is it a 1? if no then the first number is 2 long, if its yes then its 3 long, repeat.

Comment: Theoretically `82` could be either 82 or 8 and 2. Some combinations are more unlikely than others, but unless you set some real limitations this is fundamentally an irreversible algorithm. It’d be much saner to pad all numbers to three digits.

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: change `str(ord(c)` to `'{:03}'.format(ord(c)`

Comment: Now it says `unsupported format string passed to generator.__format__`

Answer (score 2):

If you limit this to printable characters ( ascii >= 32 ) in an 8 bit character set (extended ASCII), there is actually no ambiguity.  Each characters will use either 2 or 3 digits.  Characters with two digits will be >= 32 and characters with 3 digits will be <= 255 (which happens to start with a two digit number below 32). So two consecutive digits < 32 can only be the beginning of a 3 digit character.

```
def decodeStr(s):
    if s == "": return ""
    code = s[:3] if s[:2] < "32" else s[:2]
    return chr(int(code)) + decodeStr(s[len(code):])

sa = decodeStr("8297104117108")
print(sa) # "Rahul"
```

If you have a very long string to decode, the recursive approach might hit Python's maximum recursion limit.  Here is an iterative variant of the function:

```
def decodeStr(s):
    result = ""
    code   = ""
    for digit in s:
        code += digit
        if len(code) < 2 or code < "32" : continue
        result += chr(int(code))
        code = ""
    return result
```

The iterative function will run about 1.8x faster than the recursive one.

Comment: To prevent confusion, ASCII is one such 8-bit character set but it goes to 127. The algorithm implementation above applies only to ASCII and ISO 8859-1 because it uses [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) and relies on the design of Unicode, ISO-8859-1 and ASCII.

Comment: The logic will support extended ASCII codes (8 bit) but chr(int(code)) may not produce the intended character depending on the source.  It will, of course support 7 bit ASCII in all cases.  Assuming, as the OP indicated, that the source is the same platform and settings, chr(ord(x)) should return x.  I agree that this caveat needs to be noted though.

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple, but not very efficient solution:

```
d = '8297104117108'
l = []
while d:
    if d[0] == '1':
        l.append(chr(int(d[:3])))
        d = d[3:]
    else:
        l.append(chr(int(d[:2])))
        d = d[2:]
print(''.join(l))
```

this assumes that the range of you characters is pretty limited, if you can mess with the "encryption", then pad your number to be of length 3. like so:

```
my_code = ''.join('{:03}'.format(ord(c))for c in "Rahul")
```

this will give you `'082097104117108'` which you can then read 3 at a time

```
''.join([chr(int(my_code[i:i+3])) for i in range(0,len(my_code),3)])
```

Comment: You might want to be a little more specific about what you mean by "pretty limited"

Answer (score 0):

An incremental solution assuming all codes are in `range(65,650)`, so you can extend your text to all latin extensions :

```
def decode(code):
    res=''
    car=0
    for digit in code:
         car = 10*car + int(digit)
         if car >= ord('A'):
             res += chr(car)
             car=0
    return res
```

`decode('8297104117108')` is `'Rahul'`,  `decode('8297250108')`is`'Raúl'`.